# How to push new json element to all array elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Below json we are getting in response, and to this api we need to add new element for all input parameter array and send new request to server.

How to push `"inputList":[ ]` element below all array elements of `inputParameters`?

**Response:**

```
{
   "canBeSubscribed":false,
   "inputParameters":[
      {
         "allowBlank":false,
         "canBeShownOnUi":false,
         "uiControl":"1"
      },
      {
         "allowBlank":false,
         "uiControl":"1"
      }
   ],
   "reportTitle":"Report"
}
```

**New Request:**

```
{
   "canBeSubscribed":false,
   "inputParameters":[
      {
         "allowBlank":false,
         "canBeShownOnUi":false,
         "uiControl":"1",
         "inputList":[
            
         ]
      },
      {
         "allowBlank":false,
         "uiControl":"1",
         "inputList":[
            
         ]
      }
   ],
   "reportTitle":"Report_New"
}
```

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const response = {
   "canBeSubscribed":false,
   "inputParameters":[
      {
         "allowBlank":false,
         "canBeShownOnUi":false,
         "uiControl":"1"
      },
      {
         "allowBlank":false,
         "uiControl":"1"
      }
   ],
   "reportTitle":"Report"
}

const newRequest = {
  ...response,
  reportTitle: "Report_New",
  inputParameters: response.inputParameters.map((inputParameter) => ({
    ...inputParameter,
    inputList: [],
  }))
}

console.log(newRequest);
```